# Combine Row Index and Row Value (String) For Specific Rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that I have a Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(10), 'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'h', 'i']})
```

and it looks like:

```
   col1 col2
0     0    a
1     1    b
2     2    c
3     3    a
4     4    e
5     5    f
6     6    g
7     7    a
8     8    h
9     9    i
```

I want to update all values where `df['col2'] == 'a'` and append the row index to `a` so that we get:

```
   col1 col2
0     0    a_0
1     1    b
2     2    c
3     3    a_3
4     4    e
5     5    f
6     6    g
7     7    a_7
8     8    h
9     9    i
```

Comment: Why do you want to update all values where df['col2'] == 'a' and append the row index to a? That's a very non-pandas idiom. Shouldn't you really create a separate column with the index value, or NaN where `df['col2'] != 'a'`? This feels like an XY problem. what are you ultimately doing?

Comment: I need to make the rows with `a` unique from anything else within that column

Comment: ***Why*** do you say you need to do that? Are you doing some joins? Using `col2` as an index or key for further operations? Is it just formatting some text for output? Unless we know your context, we can only guess at solutions. Please post us the surrounding lines of code.

Comment: The next step is to call `pd.factorize` on `col2` after the transformation and then the resulting NumPy array will be used in an analysis elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to compare if value equals `a` and [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) col1/index after converting to string

```
df['col2']=df['col2'].mask(df['col2'].eq('a'),df['col2'].add('_'+df.index.astype(str)))

#df['col2']=df['col2'].mask(df['col2'].eq('a'),df['col2'].add('_'+df['col1'].astype(str)))

print(df)
```

---

```
   col1 col2
0     0  a_0
1     1    b
2     2    c
3     3  a_3
4     4    e
5     5    f
6     6    g
7     7  a_7
8     8    h
9     9    i
```

Comment: A `numpy` alternative `df['col2'] = np.where(df['col2'] == 'a', 'a_'+df.index.astype(str), df['col2'])`

Comment: @anky_91 For a DataFrame with many, many rows (say, 300 M), this solution seems to take up a ton of memory

Answer (score 1):

#### Comprehension

```
df.assign(col2=[f'{v}_{i}' if v == 'a' else v for i, v in df.col2.iteritems()])

   col1 col2
0     0  a_0
1     1    b
2     2    c
3     3  a_3
4     4    e
5     5    f
6     6    g
7     7  a_7
8     8    h
9     9    i
```

---

A very low memory footprint loop that edits in place

```
for i, v in df.col2.iteritems():
    if v == 'a':
        df.at[i, 'col2'] = f'a_{i}'
```